# How to get the file size&file name&file start address?

Tags: c++, qt

I use QFileDialog to open a file and use a QDatastream to read it.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open file"),
                                                    " ",
                                                    tr("Text (*.c);;Bin(*.bin)"));
    QFile f(fileName);
    QDataStream readstream(&f);
    f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

But after that ,I have to use a function written in C so I have a problem about `how to get the parameters`.

My C function is:

```
Ymodem_Transmit (uint8_t *buf, const uint8_t* sendFileName, uint32_t sizeFile)
```

1.`uint8_t *buf` is a pointer to the start address of the file ,but I dont know how to get it from QDataStream. Maybe I can read them into a buffer but my file is a little big so I don't want to use a big buffer.

2.`const uint8_t* sendFileName` is a string and how to get that? 
Even though`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` return me a `Qstring filename` but I think it includes the file's path,not exactly the filename.What I want is a real filename , I believe some class-function can do this but I can't find it.

3.`uint32_t sizeFile` Can I get it by using `qint64 QFile::​size()` ? If I was right , how can I transfer a `qint64` into `uint32_t`? Will that work if I do so:

```
qint64 filesize=QFile::​size();
(uint32_t)filesize;
```

Comment: Well you can [read data from the `QDataStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#readRawData) into a buffer. Or maybe you should rethink how you handle the file? And there are ways [to get the file name from a `QFile`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#fileName), and even ways to [get the filename without path](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#fileName).

Comment: thank you @Joachim Pileborg for your information and links of documents , which I think will help me a lot . But what if I don't use a buffer to storage ? I think use pointer is easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you not to use your C-function - `QFile` itself provides a really nice interface for accessing data in your file system. If you want to get your filename excluding a path use `QFIleInfo` class and `fileName()`member. And yes, you can get the file size this way, but be carefull - if your file size is rather big (bigger than can hold `uint32_t`) your value will be overflown.

Comment: thank you @Mikhail Zimka , and have you got some good idea about the first question I asked which is how to get the pointer of an opened file ? I dont't really want to use a buffer to storage the file. If I can get the pointer to the beginning address of the file , things will be very easy.

Comment: @ctxrr, I don't really know what you are talking about...QFile itself (as like as  a c-FILE*) doesn't allocate any memory for the content of the file - it just provides an interface for reading. But according to the arguments of your function I can guess, that the first arg specifies destination address - a memory the file content would be read to. Clarify it, please